# PHP mpdf6 background image

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I'm trying to create a PDF from html whith mPDF (version 6.0) pratically all is right, but the 'background-image' don't work, I try whith mPDF 5.0 but don't change anything, I try whith tables, divs and others elements but don't work.

PHP:

```
$firstCabec = "
        <table id='test'>
            <tr><td id='testeZuado'> adsjkbfkasbçlkjf açlkhfçl jahsçljfaskçjsklasjhkjjas lkg  dj aslk jjd klajs dçalkjks bdlk absfkj blksabfka jbklfblskjabf kljsbdf b</td></tr>
        </table> "
```

CSS:

```
#test{
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';  
    color: #3864B2; 
    background-image: url('cabecalho_relatorios_1.png'); 
    height: 160px;  
    width: 100%;
}
```

can someone help me?

Comment: Does this page renders properly? I mean if we try to view these contents instead sending it to pdf.

Comment: it's works when I saw like html.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of invalid UTF-8 characters present in your HTML.

Try,

`$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8');`

Before,

`$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);`